# PHP imap_functions get attachments OLE format

Tags: php, gmail, imap, attachment, ole

It's possible get email from gmail account, but only get emails with OLE attachments?

I'm using this code:

```
<?php 
/* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = '';
$password = '';
try {
/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {

    /* begin output var */
    $output = '';

    /* put the newest emails on top */
    rsort($emails);

    /* for every email... */
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {


        /* get information specific to this email */
        $structureb = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number,0);
        echo "<h1>imap_fetchstructure</h1><pre>";
        print_r($structureb);
        echo "</pre>";

        /* get information specific to this email */
        $structureb = imap_body($inbox, $email_number,0);
        echo "<h1>imap_fetchstructure</h1><pre>";
        print_r($structureb);
        echo "</pre>";


        /* get information specific to this email */
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number,0);
        echo "<h1>imap_fetchstructure</h1><pre>";
        print_r($structure);
        echo "</pre>";

        /* get information specific to this email */
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        echo "<h1>imap_fetch_overview</h1><pre>";
        print_r($overview);
        echo "</pre>";

        $attachments = array();
        if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) {

            for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) {

                $attachments[$i] = array(
                    'is_attachment' => false,
                    'filename' => '',
                    'name' => '',
                    'attachment' => ''
                );

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) {
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($connection, $message_number, $i+1);
                    if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) { // 3 = BASE64
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                    elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) { // 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        echo "<h3>final</h3><pre>";
        print_r($attachments);
        echo "</pre>";


            /* output the email header information */
            $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
            $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
            $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
            $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
            $output.= '</div>';

            /* output the email body */
            $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
            echo $output;
            break;
        }

        echo $output;
    } 

    /* close the connection */
    imap_close($inbox); 
} catch (Exception $e) {
    throw new Exception("Error Processing Request = " . $e->getMessage(), 1);

}
```

But when i search in this several functions something that indicate is a OLE attachment i can't found anything.

Exist some way to get emails with OLE attachments?

Comment: Look at the content-type of each attachment (ie. text/plain, application/ms-tnef, image/jpeg, whatever). It should be in your $structure.

Comment: What is an OLE attachment?